# Run MSAccess pass through query thats runs SQL stored proc asynchronously

Tags: sql, t-sql, ms-access

As title says trying to run pass through query asynchrnously.

I have tried

```
db.Execute "QrySSRSOneParameter", dbRunAsync
```

but this doesnt work.

So I found this code that passes the SQL statement through.

I run the following code but a get a

```
Could not find stored procedure 'sptest'.
```

It does exist.

```
Set ws = DBEngine.CreateWorkspace("ODBCWorkspace", "LESTERASSOCIATE\Malcolm", "access", dbUseODBC)
Set myconn = ws.OpenConnection("TestConnection", dbRunAsync, False, connstring)
Set myqry = myconn.CreateQueryDef("", "EXECUTE sptest")
myconn.Execute "EXECUTE sptest", dbRunAsync
Set myconn = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

just looking at this code briefly and one thing struck me.

you're setting your connection then creating a query def... then not using the query def

shouldn't the execute line read

```
myqry.execute(dbRunAsync)
```